# Binary file read error

Tags: c++, binary

Run no problem for the first time,but when I comment on a part of the code,Program termination:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images of *text*, especially links to images. If the links go stale, your question become worthless. Instead copy-paste the text info the body of the question. Please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can you please share your code here ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to read objects you can't really save to files, or load from files.

Lets take that `std::string` member `name`. A `std::string` objects is basically just a *pointer* to a dynamically allocated array of characters (i.e. a C-style zero-terminated string), plus the length of the contained string. The problem is two-fold: First is that when attempting to save the `name` object it doesn't save the string, but the pointer; And the second problem is that pointers to dynamically allocated data are unique per process.

What happens when you load the object is that you read and set the pointer, but only the pointer. This pointer was valid in the process that wrote the object, but not in the current process, it doesn't point to any valid memory allocated by your process. Using this pointer, which is done when you use the string object, will then lead to *undefined behavior*, and UB us one of the most common reasons for crashes.

What you need to do is to [*serialize*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) the string. If you want to write the code yourself and not use a library for it (there are many great serialization libraries you can use) then you need to write the string length as a fixed-sized integer, then write the actual string data. When you *deserialize* you first must know that the next piece of data to read is a string, and then read the length, followed by the string data, and then construct your string object from that.

Comment: I added include<string>,but it's still wrong . What should I do to change the code?